# Effect of internet connection speed on solo mining

Tags: litecoin, hash, solo-mining, mining-setup, bandwidth

I have a set of PCs hasing at 100 kH/s and currently the network difficulty is 2674.36329706.

My power usage is 200 W, and as per https://www.litecoinpool.org/calc?hashrate=100&difficulty=2674.36329706&power=200&energycost=0.12&currency=USD

the probability of me finding a block in 30 days is 2.23%

However, my internet speed has been curtailed at 52 kilobytes-per-second and I'm wondering if that changes the above probability from 2% to zero? ie, do I need to have a great internet connection to even have that 2% chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With solo mining, all you *need* to get from the Internet is the latest block. Since these come once every 2.5 minutes (average) and are [at most 250 KB](https://litecoin.info/Litecoin.conf) ([typically ~10 KB](http://block-explorer.com/)), you should be just fine. You'd also want to get all the latest Litecoin network traffic in order to validate all the transactions you can, but that'd be pretty small, like the blocks.

You might find (on average) a few more stale blocks than the typical high-speed user, but this shouldn't be too significant: on the order of (your latency and download time - normal latency and download time)/2.5 minutes

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My mistake, but the same principles apply. I've modified my post to reference Litecoin's details.